# SSD wear-leveling count goes up by 1TB in one day without much activity

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd

I have a 250GB SSD. The wear-leveling count went up to above 2000 in just a few months of use (as reported by SMART self-tests). It doesn't feel right.
Today, it increased by 4 since 24 hours ago, which should mean all sectors were written to about 4 times on average, which means about 1TB of data has been written to the disk? There's no such activity on this machine in the past 24 hours.
Most attribute values from SMART tests show as N/A as well, is this normal?
How does one identify the problem here? Could it be some kernel bug related to TRIM?

Comment: There *were* known issues with **Windows** damaging SSD's (https://www.tomsguide.com/news/windows-10-update-could-kill-your-ssd-what-you-need-to-know), but not Linux, AFAIK. Check what background processes are running.

Comment: You missed to post important data such as manufacturer and model of your drive and a SMART report as issued by the smartmontools software.

Comment: It's ADATA. I went to get the smart report and apparently I hadn't done the self-test for a while. I ran the self-test and all the attributes populated now. The wear-leveling count is still going up a lot. It went up by 6 since I posted this question 20 hours ago. Is it because it works by 32MB blocks? Like even if you only write 1MB it will up the count for an entire 32MB block? The lifetime percentage says 97% left...so total erase count for the drive would be 87000?? For a cheapo SSD that sounds abnormally high?

Comment: I asked for a SMART report but instead you are guessing around. My help finishes here.

Comment: Please provide your full SMART report if you expect someone to help.

Comment: Please stop babbling about the SMART values and post them.